# How to find the ID of a views block that is not assigned to a region?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

The title pretty much says it all. I need to find the ID of a Views block that is not assigned to any region, in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit that view, move your mouse on the "block" that you need to analyze and see the url.Like this one:

http://mydomain.ext/admin/structure/views/view/flag_bookmarks/edit/page_4

The last url path is the page id: page_4. 
In your case all start with "block_".